# Call to undefined method Shell::getAssociated()

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, model

I got a subj error when I creating some models.
I use the last cake version and windows 7.
So, what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you seeing this issue from console or browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably issue with include_path, check if cake library is included in `php.ini`'s `include_path=".;c:/php5/cake"`

Answer (score 1):

Okay I solved problem. The problem was because I have database table named 'shells' and when I baked model via 'cake bake' there was generated model 'shells.php' which overrided core class 'Shell'.